# Sanitizing random data type

Tags: php, xss, sanitization

i have a problem with sanitizing data.

Is there a built in php function to sanitize data like htmlspecialchars/htmlenteties, which if provided a non string value it keeps its original type.
Example:

```
The problem:
    $a = 1;//(int);
    $b = htmlspecialchars($a);
    var_dump($b); // string "1"
The desired effect:
    $a = 1;//(int);
    $b = htmlspecialchars($a);
    var_dump($b); // integer"1"
```

Thanks for the time.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` seems useless on integers

Comment: if you just want to check if its a number int/float use is_numeric()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$a = 1;//(int);
$b = htmlspecialchars($a);
settype($b,gettype($a));
var_dump($b); // integer"1"
```

Results in

```
int(1)
```

Comment: Yes but i don`t know the type of $a (integer was just an example). But come to think about it, i could first get the type of $a and then use to cast it, but i think this is too much work, having htmlspecialchars/htmlenteties working for sanitizing only strings.Thanks
The more i think, i get to the conclusion that checking if it is string and only then using those functions is the best way.

Comment: I've edited my post with another solution (thanks to your idea). Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by type first, then use a `htmlspecialchars` and then cast to the type... although that would defy the use of htmlspecial chars. Also, i think the `$a` will probably come from some request variable, which will always be a string in that case.

It almost sounds as if you would like a function to determine the context for you. Since if it is already typed int, what 'escaping' do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use htmlspecialchars on an integer value.

I just get the type, and do something like i show in the code below, even you can settype again later.

```
$var_type = gettype($var);

switch ($var_type)
{
    case 'integer':
         break;
    case 'string':
         $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
}

return $var;
```